# How to gain row value of button clicked in a radgrid's DetailTable

Tags: asp.net, telerik

If I were to want to gain the value of a row in the master table in a template column button I would do:
    " OnCommand=event>

Event

```
GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)RadGrid1.Items[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgumrnt)];
```

I am not sure what index the grid returns when the detailtable button is clicked and every time I try to access a column in that row I get an error saying column does not exist. I tried doing so:

```
GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)RadGrid1.MasterTable.DetailTables[0].Items[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgumrnt)];
```

This did not work as well.

Excuse me if I made any mistakes, I am on my mobile phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a much simpler solution to my problem that doesn't if require me to use oncommand or command argument! Instead I use the simple Onclick.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)btn.NamingContainer;
    TableCell cell = (TableCell)item["UniqueName"];
    string value = cell.Text;
}
```